# How to watch new entry files with webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have `webpack.config.js` which produces html files corresponding to each pug-source template:

```js
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  entry: glob.sync('src/*.pug').reduce((acc, value) => {
      acc[value] = './' + value;
      return acc;
    }, {}),
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.pug$/, use: [
        "file-loader?name=[name].html",
        "extract-loader",
        "html-loader",
        "pug-html-loader"
      ] },
    ]
  }
};
```

It works fine, when I run webpack-dev-server I can navigate to produced html files in browser. But I also want webpack to watch and process new entry files while dev server is running. How can I achieve that?

Comment: entry files must be js files, AFAIK you can't have `import/require` statements inside a pug file, and webpack does not understand that as an entry point.

Comment: No, entry files can be of any type. The sample I provided is working fine as I mension. And I didn't include any import/require statement in pugs. The questions is about watching new files.